# Sort Array of structs in Spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

Consider the following dataframe:

```
case class ArrayElement(id:Long,value:Double)

val df = Seq(
  Seq(
    ArrayElement(1L,-2.0),ArrayElement(2L,1.0),ArrayElement(0L,0.0)
  )
).toDF("arr")

df.printSchema

root
 |-- arr: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- value: double (nullable = false)
```

Is there a way to sort `arr` by `value` other than using an udf?

I've seen `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.sort_array`, what is this method actually doing in the case of complex array elements? Is it sorting the array by the first element (i.e. `id`?)

Comment: [spark functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html) says "Sorts the input array for the given column in ascending order, according to the natural ordering of the array elements."

Comment: @RameshMaharjan of course I have read the API docs, but it's not clear for me what "natural ordering" means.

Comment: It will sort your structs by the value only if the `id` is same. Otherwise a sorted array based on the natural ordering of `id` will be returned. I don't think there's any other way apart from a UDF here. Let us know if you do find something.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[spark functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html) says "Sorts the input array for the given column in ascending order, according to the natural ordering of the array elements."

Before I explain, lets look at some examples of what sort_array does.

```
+----------------------------+----------------------------+
|arr                         |sorted                      |
+----------------------------+----------------------------+
|[[1,-2.0], [2,1.0], [0,0.0]]|[[0,0.0], [1,-2.0], [2,1.0]]|
+----------------------------+----------------------------+

+----------------------------+----------------------------+
|arr                         |sorted                      |
+----------------------------+----------------------------+
|[[0,-2.0], [2,1.0], [0,0.0]]|[[0,-2.0], [0,0.0], [2,1.0]]|
+----------------------------+----------------------------+

+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
|arr                          |sorted                       |
+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
|[[0,-2.0], [2,1.0], [-1,0.0]]|[[-1,0.0], [0,-2.0], [2,1.0]]|
+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

so sort_array is sorting by checking on the first element and then second and so on for each element in an array in the defined column

I hope its clear